# Trouble with groovy/java, classpaths, and reflection/dynamic method access

Tags: java, groovy, reflection

TL;DR:  I am having trouble with classpaths and a java/groovy execution environment.  Java is openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18.  Groovy is groovy-4.0.12.jar.

#### The Background

I have Java program that loads groovy scripts and runs them.  The script can access a number of resource in the parent via an `ExecutionContext` class that is setup upon initialization.  The design uses a base class to standardize the interface, leaving task-specific codes to the subclass.  A quick example:

```
BaseClass.1.groovy:

import org.bson.*;
class BaseClass {
    ExecutionContext exe; 

    public void setContext(ExecutionContext executingEnvironment) {
        this.exe = executingEnvironment
    }
              
    Document fetchSection(String name) {
    return exe.fetchSection(name);
    }
}

MyClass.groovy:
import BaseClass;

import org.bson.*;

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    void do_something(Document inputs) {
    Document s1 = fetchSection("S1"); // use BaseClass method
...
     }    
}
```

`ExecutionContext` is defined in a simple class and placed into a jar `ExecutionContext.jar`:

```
import org.bson.*;

public interface ExecutionContext {
    Document fetchSection(String sectionName);
}
```

The parent program contains a concrete implementation of `ExecutionContext`:

```
    class ExecutionContextImpl implements ExecutionContext {
    public Document fetchSection(String sectionName) {
        // Actual work here...
    }
    }
```

The parent first loads the `BaseClass`, then `MyClass`, then creates an instance of `MyClass`, then creates an instance of `ExecutionContext` and using reflection sets it into `MyClass`:

```
GroovyClassLoader cls = new GroovyClassLoader();

String fwscript = get BaseClass.1.groovy from somewhere;
String myscript = get MyClass.groovy from somewhere;

Class fwclazz = cls.parseClass(fwscript);
Class clazz = cls.parseClass(myscript);
Object oo = clazz.newInstance(); 

ExecutionContext qqq = new ExecutionContextImpl();

Class[] argTypes = new Class[1];
argTypes[0] = ExecutionContext.class;
java.lang.reflect.Method m = fwclazz.getDeclaredMethod("setContext", argTypes);
Object[] margs = new Object[1];
margs[0] = qqq;
Object oo2 = m.invoke(oo, margs);
```

**This works**, and later use of dynamic reflection to invoke methods such as `do_something` also works:

```
Class[] argTypes = new Class[1];
argTypes[0] = Document.class;
java.lang.reflect.Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod( "do_something", argTypes);
Object[] margs = new Object[1];
margs[0] = new Document("adj", 6.3);
Object oo2 = m.invoke(oo, margs);
```

#### The Problem

I wish to isolate the groovy classpath environment from the parent.  This can be done as follows; note the `null` in arg #2 to prevent the new classloader from inheriting the environment from the parent program:

```
URL[] groovyClasspath = new URL[] {
    new File("/path/to/ExecutionContext.jar").toURI().toURL(),
    new File("/path/to/groovy-4.0.12.jar").toURI().toURL(),
    new File("/path/to/guava-17.0.jar").toURI().toURL(),
    new File("/path/to/bson-4.9.0.jar").toURI().toURL()
};
URLClassLoader cpl = new URLClassLoader(groovyClasspath, null);
```

This *almost* works.  The scripts parse and in particular, resources referenced in the scripts like `imports` and `bson` and `Table` objects are resolved.  Commenting out the URL in the classpath produces an expected `unable to resolve class` runtime exception so it is definitely finding the intended codes.  The problem is that with an explicit classpath, the groovy environment cannot seem to find methods in the loaded groovy scripts.  This call:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method m = fwclazz.getDeclaredMethod("setContext", argTypes);
```

throws an exception `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: BaseClass.setContext(ExecutionContext)`.  Any call to `getDeclaredMethod` for either the base class `fwclazz` or the subclass `MyClass` has this problem.  And what is weird is that if I list the methods with something like this:

```
for (Method method : fwclazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
   System.out.println("  " + method.toString());
}
```

Then I clearly see `public void BaseClass.setContext(ExecutionContext)`:

```
  public groovy.lang.MetaClass BaseClass.getMetaClass()
  public void BaseClass.setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass)
  protected groovy.lang.MetaClass BaseClass.$getStaticMetaClass()
  public org.bson.Document BaseClass.fetchSection(java.lang.String)
  public void BaseClass.setContext(ExecutionContext)
  public static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup BaseClass.$getLookup()
  public ExecutionContext BaseClass.getExe()
  public void BaseClass.setExe(ExecutionContext)
```

I am sure there is a very simple addition to the `GroovyClassLoader` `URL` list to make this work.  Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You have in your code a class literal `ExecutionContext.class`. This class will be resolved with the defining class loader of your code containing this expression.

Then, you create a new class loader using `new URLClassLoader(groovyClasspath, null)`, having the bootstrap class loader as its parent. So it can’t resolve the class name `ExecutionContext` to the class described above, as it doesn’t even know about the class loader. But apparently, you have added a version of that class to the new class loader’s path (I suppose “ExecutionContext.jar”).

Therefore, you have two different classes with the name `ExecutionContext`, loaded by different class loaders. These do not match when looking up a method.

You can set up a parent for your new class loader like `new URLClassLoader(groovyClasspath, ExecutionContext.class.getClassLoader())` which ensures that the new class loader will see the same `ExecutionContext` class than your code. The class loader tries the parent loader before trying to load a class itself. The best strategy is not to add sources to your new class loader for classes already available to the parent loader, to emphasize which loader is supposed to load which class.

Comment: `ExecutionContext.class.getClassLoader()` will get the parent program classloader with the parent classpath which is what I don't want.  Your suggestion is sound but I need, for example, for the script to load and use guava-2.4.jar "safely" while the parent might be using guava-3.0.

Comment: Then, there is no way around using at least three class loaders, one as the parent for the other two, to load all the classes they must agree on, and the other two to form different namespaces for the different versions of the classes.

Comment: I put it together as you suggested and it works -- really well. Actually kills 2 birds with one stone by eliminating the classpath on the command line invocation.   Everything is dynamic data driven, which permits significantly greater control over resources and their location including not pulling jars from a filesystem but rather a database.